# I'm trying to see if a smaller string is contained within another larger string and I want to split the string

Tags: java, string

I'm working on an algorithm that helps predict what a computer might do in a rock paper scissors shoe game. Basically what I've done is I played it 100 times and wrote down all its moves. I made its moves into a string.

What I'm doing is looking for patterns in the behavior of the computer, just like I would with a person. For the first four rounds, I'm having my algorithm just guess. However, after the first four rounds, I take the computer's moves and compare them to the training data. If I can find the pattern, I look to the next move. For example let's say part of the data looks like:

R P P S S S P R

and I found the computer said R P P S, my algorithm would recommend that I do Scissors (S) because that's what it did last time.

What I'm doing is I'm saving the training data as a string, getting the input data and also saving it as a string, and then trying to split the training data string, but it doesn't seem to be working.

How do I split a string, using a smaller string that is contained within the larger string, so I may save and print the next character after the smaller string contained in the larger string?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int rock = 50;
        int paper = 32;
        int sicsors = 18;

        //it should pick rock 1/2 the time, paper 1/3 the time, and scissors 1/5 the time
        //Look at history and look at past four. 
        //If you can find a pattern then  whatever comes next use

        //char[] trainingData = "beep".toCharArray();
        //char[] gameInput = "beep".toCharArray();

        String userInput = "";
        String trainingDataString = "RRRRSPPPSRRRP";

        ArrayList<String> trainingData = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> gameInput = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> testingData = new ArrayList<String>();




        System.out.println("Lets start!");
        System.out.println("Play 100 roudds of RPC!");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to continue");
        int x = scan.nextInt();

        scan.nextLine();

        int rounds = 0;

        boolean patternedContained = true;
        while (rounds < 100) {
            rounds++;
            //choose based on overall perctanges
            if (rounds <= 4 || patternedContained == false) {
                int compChoice = rand.nextInt(100);
                //System.out.println(compChoice);
                if(compChoice <= 20) {
                    System.out.println("Use Rock. Enter the robots choice (R P S). ");
                    userInput = scan.nextLine();
                    gameInput.add(userInput);
                }
                else if (compChoice > 20 && compChoice <= 32) {
                    System.out.println("Use Paper. Enter the robots choice (R P S).");
                    userInput = userInput + scan.nextLine();
                    gameInput.add(userInput);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Use Scissors. Enter the robots choice (R P S).");
                    userInput = userInput + scan.nextLine();
                    gameInput.add(userInput);
                }
            }
            else if (rounds > 4) {
                //check if pattern is contained 
                //if it is 
                if(trainingDataString.toLowerCase().contains(userInput.toLowerCase())) {
                String[] startHere = trainingDataString.split(userInput);
                String gotCha = startHere[0];
                System.out.println(gotCha);


                }


            }
        }


        System.out.println(userInput);





    }

}
```

Comment: Removing tag machine-learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `indexOf` to find the starting position of the little string inside the big string:

```
int littleStringPos = bigString.indexOf(littleString);
```

You can then find the index of the character immediately following the little string by adding the little string's length to its starting position:

```
int charAfterIdx = littleStringIdx + littleString.length();
```

Then use `charAt` to pick out the character:

```
char charAfterLittleString = bigString.charAt(charAfterIdx);
```

You should be prepared for the possibility that the big string does not contain the little string, which would be indicated by `indexOf` returning a result of -1.  So a correct implementation, with intermediate variable removed and safety check included, could be something like this:

```
int littleStringPos = bigString.indexOf(littleString);
if (littleStringPos >= 0) 
    System.out.println("The character after thelittle string is: " + 
        bigString.charAt(littleStringIdx + littleString.length()));
else
    System.out.println("The little string isn't there!");
```